# it says that it cant find symbol refering to arraylist commands, like ".get" ".add" yes im very new to java

Tags: java

It says that it cant find symbol referring to `arraylist` commands, like ".get" ".add".

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ProductPrices {
        
        private ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();
        private ArrayList<Double> prices = new ArrayList<Double>();

        public ProductPrices(String products, double prices) {
            
            //this.products() = products();
            //this.prices() = prices();
        }

        public void put(String products, double prices) {
            
            for(int i=0; i<products.size(); i++){
                products.add(i);
            }
            for(int i=0; i<prices.size(); i++){
                prices.add(i);
            
                ArrayList<String> mergePriceProduct = new ArrayList<String>(products.get(i) + prices.get(i));
                
            }
            products() = mergePriceProduct();

        }
        public double get(String products) {
            
            Iterator<String> productIter = products.iterator();
            while (proditer.hasNext()){ 
            System.out.println(prodIter.nextString());
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Your method parameters are shadowing the instance variables. Ie you have a list called products, but you also have a variable callled products of type string. and string doesn't have add. if you add this.products.add() it will work

Comment: Actually there are a lot of other mistakes in your code as well. but its not so easy to understand what you want to achieve here... It's probably best you study up a bit more on Java.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has couple of issues, but specifically in context of `get` and `add` methods, you are facing variable shadowing.

> Shadowing refers to the practice in Java programming of using two
> variables with the same name within scopes that overlap. When you do
> that, the variable with the higher-level scope is hidden because the
> variable with lower-level scope overrides it. The higher-level
> variable is then “shadowed.”

In your case the class level variable name to `ArrayList` of **products and prices** is same as your local variable of method put and get. If you want to refer class level variable:

1. Either rename one of the variable
2. Or use class level variable with this keyword as `this.prices`